# Ubuntu Font Family in TCPDF document

Tags: fonts, tcpdf

I have no luck trying to embed Ubuntu fonts in PDF document created with TCPDF (http://font.ubuntu.com/).

Only thing that works is with bold font, but I need to use regular:

```
$fontname = $pdf->addTTFfont('../fonts/ubuntu/Ubuntu-R.ttf', 'TrueTypeUnicode', '', 96);
$pdf->SetFont('Ubuntu', 'B', 8, '', true);
```

When I try with anything else (ie. `$pdf->SetFont('Ubuntu', 'R', 8, '', true);`) it returns error: TCPDF ERROR: Could not include font definition file: ubuntu.

Can you help me how to manage this? Is there problem in font itself?

Tnx in adv!

Answer (score 0):

$pdf->SetFont('ubuntur', '', 8, '', true);